# TreeView - Changing Text binding of textblock dynamically (part of item template)

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a user control that contains a TreeView Control.
I'd like to set the `**binding**` of the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` used in the `TreeView`'s `ItemTemplate`, based on the value of a dependency property called `NodeDisplayProperty` of the TreeViewUserControl class.

I tried something similar to what shown below (but setting the correct data context for `NodeDisplayProperty`), but it doesn't work as the `Text` property of `TextBlock` refuses the 'double binding'.

The property `DisplayMemberPath` of `TreeView` can't be set either, as I'm using an item template.

Any suggestions that don't involve writing a new binding class?
Ideally I'd like a XAML solution, but if you do it in the code behind, how do you access the
binding for the code block in the XAML-defined item template?

**Edit:** items displayed in the tree are from the model, so they have no visibility on UI elements.

Thanks!

```
    <UserControl x:Class="TreeViewUserControl">
        <Grid>
            <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Hierarchy}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="treeHierarchy" SelectedItemChanged="treeHierarchySelectedItemChanged" >
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
   <!-- Here --- -->    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path={Binding NodeDisplayProperty}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="13" >
                            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Command="userControls:Commands.RemoveNode">
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <!-- ... -->
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </TreeView>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Comment: Why not directly expose what should be shown instead of returning the name of the property that contains it?

Comment: The name of the property that gets bound depends on the options the user has selected via UI.

Comment: As i said, you could have a property that directly returns the value. How this can be realized depends on what level the user selection happens. For example if it's at the top level for the whole tree every item needs to be able to look it up to then return the relevant value.

Comment: Items displayed are of model classes, so they have no visibility on UI  types. Question updated :)

Comment: That does not matter, i am not talking about the UI but the classes representing the tree as a whole and the items. If you have no class for the tree but just nodes that does not matter, your nodes just need to know what the user selected, this information should be in *some* model if not the nodes themselves.

Comment: I don't agree. A model class that represents a business entity (in this case a hierarchical business structure) and which is used in many different areas of the application shouldn't implement facilities that are purely required by the UI. Maybe a model view class would be appropriate here. I'd still like to a solution to the original problem :)

Comment: Well yes, i was talking about view-models as you usually would not want to directly put your model into the tree because of selection and expansion. Also if i had known of any solution i would have written an answer instead of a comment in the first place.